# How to divide a 300*200 Lattice Boltzman cube across 16 cores - MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to parallel programming using MPI... I need to parallelize a 300x200 Lattice Boltzman cube.. I managed chunking row wise by dividing 200 into chunks depending on size... However my code works only when there are 4 and 8 cores... I need to run the program on 16 cores..Can anyone please direct me as to how to divide 200 for 16 cores..

I am splitting currently in the following manner:

```
.
.
.
MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );

/* size and rank will become ubiquitous */ 
/* get no of process (size) & rank of each proces*/
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );

start=  (200 / size) * rank;
end = start + (200 / size);

.
.
.
for(ii=start;ii<end;ii++) {
   for(jj=0;jj<300;jj++)
.
. 
.
}

.
.
```

CLearly the above technique would work only if 200%size = 0, for 16 cores size=16, and hence the approach would fail.. Could anyone please suggest a more generalized chunking approach approach..which would make the program independent (if possible) of number of cores I would be running it on..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix that would be to calculate 'start' and 'end' as

```
slice_size = (200 + size - 1)/size; // max. amount of rows per core
start = rank * slice_size;
end = min(start + slice_size, 200);
```

In this case, some cores can be underloaded.

A better scalability could be achieved if the lattice is divided not by rows only, but both by rows and columns, or even in non-rectangular areas, for example, using a linear representation of the lattice, like this:

```
total_cells = rows * columns;
common_piece_size = (total_cells + size - 1) / size;
start = rank * common_piece_size;
end = min(start + common_piece_size, total_size);

for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
  row = i / columns;
  col = i % columns;
  // process cell [col, row]
}
```

. This would require more complex inter-process communication though.

Comment: Thanks.. So I would need to communicate in north south east west all the directions right?... but wouldn't the communication overhead be more in that case?

Comment: It depends. Usually supercomputers have very fast network, and on a multi-core systems modern MPI implementations use shared memory automatically. Of course you should minimize communications (especially blocking ones) where possible, but load balancing per core is quite essential for scalability. Of course if number of cores will never go higher than 20, you may be ok splitting by rows only and possibly underloading the last core, so that the whole utilization would be still > 95%.

Comment: If I do.. end = min(start + 200/size, 200); for size =16.. the last 8 rows are still left unevaluated.. How can I evaluate those remaining cells too.. ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's my mistake. You should use `(200+size-1)/size` instead of `200/size` everywhere then (in `start`'s calculation as well!). I've fixed the answer.

Comment: No worries... I tried slicing it the way you recommended but I am not getting the correct result...Just to make sure I am doing it in a correct way.. I am sending the messages in north & south direction .. does it require any more communication?  ALso i am still dividing the for loop as for(ii=start;ii<end;ii++) {
   for(jj=0;jj<300;jj++) .... } ... Is it alright..?

Comment: North and south sound good. Try printing out start and end for each core. And maybe underloading the last core makes the program fail (e.g. if you expect all cores to have the same number of rows).

Comment: Yes underloading indeed was the cause.. I changed it to divide the remainder to each process..